# Configuration management import error

Tags: 8, version-control, configuration

I use a CMI workflow with Git.

1. I made configuration changes on Dev
2. pulled them into Production
3. now when I go to `admin/config/development/configuration` and try to
   import All I get this error:

> The configuration cannot be imported because it failed validation for
>   the following reasons: Entities exist of type Taxonomy term en
>   Vocabulary Catalog. These entities need to be deleted before
>   importing.

What do I have to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what it says. You seem to be deleting the Catalog vocabulary. You need to delete all terms in it first.

Comment: Ok. But is this only for one time? Because the next time I import new configurations in the production site (the site is live and up and running), it's then not an option to delete all those terms...

Comment: Do you want to delete the vocabulary and its terms or not? You can only delete it once, so by definition, it is a one time thing. If you however do *not* want to delete it, then something else is wrong. Those terms will be gone, they will not be re-created.

Comment: Yes I can delete them now, because it's still in test. But my workflow is as follows: 1) I down sync my Production database (snapshot of live site database), with all the content, nodes, taxonomy terms etc) and import it into Dev environment 2) I make new changes and configurations on Dev. 3) export those configurations with `drush cex` and pull them into Production. If I follow this workflow I don't have to delete the Catalog terms again, isn't it? It's a one time thing?

Comment: I'm not asking if you can delete them. I'm asking if you *want* to. If you deleted that vocabulary on your dev site and are deploying that now, then you have to delete the terms and everything is working just like it is supposed to., If that's not your intention then your process is wrong. A config import is everything. You can't make changes on prod and on dev and then deploy the dev changes while keeping the prod changes too. Either copy the production DB first as you said and then only make changes on dev, or you need to use git or so to merge both change sets together.

Comment: Sorry now I am a bit lost. To be sure: 1) Taxonomy the Vocabulary is part of Drupal CMI and so the Vocabulary will be transported in Drupal 8 Configuration Management, isn't it? 2) The terms themselves are not part of CMI. They are content and part of the Database and will not be transported during Configuration Management, isn't it? 3) So to make the import working and start over again, do I have to delete the Vocabulary Catalog and it's terms on Production and on Dev. 4) Then create the Vocabulary again and export that Vocabulary (Catalog) with Drupal Configuration Management. Correct?

Comment: Forget about CMI. I am asking one question: Do you want to delete the Catalog Vocabulary?

Comment: I want to delete it, if I can somehow bring it back again and create it again?

Comment: what are the steps I have to do now? 1) delete the Vocabulary Catalog and terms on Production 2) After this it should work and I will be able to import all the configuration from Dev? 3) If I am wright, I don't have to delete my Vocabulary Catalog on my Dev environment isn't it? Because I need this Vocabulary and if I am correct, this Vocabulary (not the terms) will be imported from Dev with my CMI import. Is that correct?